# Is it safe to use Generator function instead of normal function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, generator

They are the same when **yield** is absent, of course not the same at the running phase.

```
function* add(x, y) {
    return x + y;
}  

var it = add(2, 3); 

it.next();
```

and

```
function add(x, y){
    return x + y;
}

add(2, 3);
```

**As a habit**, Is it safe and Okay to use them instead of normal functions?
despite of performance.

Comment: If there’s no reason to use a generator function, don’t. There isn’t in this example. If you have a different real-world use in mind, please write about that.

Comment: Avoid opinionated debate by stating exactly what you mean with "Okay to use them" - are you looking for cases where `generator_func().next().value` behaves differently from `func()` or are you looking for compatibility issues or ...?

Comment: I just feel it could be a good idea to use generator instead of normal functions at all, just like `let` and `const` in comparison with `var`.
So in this case there is no need to switch.

Comment: it a bit over the top to use generator functions for plain functions.

Comment: Please just close this question. It's asking purely subjective/qualitative things like "is it safe?", "is it ok?"

Comment: It's just a question of mine! that's it!

Comment: "So in this case there is no need to switch" --- how about not using numbers anymore? And using strings everywhere, so you "don't need to switch"?

Comment: I am totally rational. Context switches are hard, how about abandoning numbers and booleans in favour of strings?

Comment: Okay, in this case they are not the same! so simple!

Comment: Now you see how your question is subjective don't you.

Comment: `const` and `let` effectively replace `var`. Generator functions do not replace normal functions, and they’re very rarely useful.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it safe?

As long as your environment supports generator functions (most legacy environments don't), then sure, it's "safe". If you want to support legacy environments, then you'll have to transpile your program.

> Is it okay?

If its your program and only you have to maintain it, do whatever you want. But if you're working with other people or publishing something for community use, there's no way other programmers are going to want to use the generator API (`f(x).next().value`) for everything when an ordinary function call (`f(x)`) would suffice

> ...despite of performance

Does this imply that you know generators have awful performance compared to an ordinary function? I don't have benchmarks, but I would estimate generators are at least 10x slower than an ordinary function, if not more so.

> ...So in this case there is no need to switch

There's never going to be some point in JavaScript future where everyone goes back to their old programs and updates all the functions to use generators instead. Generators have a very specific set of use cases and it would be rather silly to use them where an ordinary function does the job just fine.